# How to exploit system call when the full path of binary is given inside the call?

Tags: linux, c, system-compromise

I was working on a challenge where I have to exploit a C program to gain elevated privileges in a linux system. To complete it I have to call a program `/bin/test` while the vulnerable program is running with elevated privilege level. The relevant code snippet is given below.

I was able to exploit another program which used `system("cat <some file>")` without a problem. In that case I created a C program with which executed `/bin/test` , named it cat and kept it in a directory which I later added to the `$PATH` variable.

However in this case I am unable to follow the above approach for two different reasons.

1. I am unable to locate the binary for `export` command.
2. I am unable to create a `$PATH` variable which will call my custom `file` command as the full path is being called in the `system()` of the program to be exploited.
3. Also note that the program sanitizes semicolon and a couple of special characters which makes it difficult to append multiple commands in the system call.

Comment: `export` is not a binary on the filesystem, but a shell built-in. You should probably read on that and anything else that you find unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have compiled the program and I can execute the "id" command by providing

```
`id`
```

as arg on stdin. Looks like they missed the backtick as forbidden character. Maybe you can create a sh script that creates a root user...

Comment: You are a life saver @kaidentity. I am dumb. I shouldn't have forgotten about backtick

Comment: Actually, I shouldn't have told you ;-) I'm a big fan of the OSCP, my reply should've been "try harder!"

Comment: Oh! is this one from the OSCP? I didn't know that. I was doing this as part of a Unix System Security class.

Comment: No, it is not, but this exercise is very typical and none would've had helped you ;-) Anyway, good luck with your exercises.